# Add one legend to layout plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, legend

I would like to create one legend for a `layout` plot in Julia. Here is some reproducible code:

```
using Plots
plot(rand(100, 4), layout = 4, color = [:red :blue :green :yellow])
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see it shows nicely a legend to each subplot, but I would like to have one shared legend, using `:shared` doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add a shared legend to a layout plot in `Julia`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this answer can give an idea. I can do it by a trick (creating a transparent plot for the legend). The only problem is that I don't know how I can move the legend (actually, the transparent plot) to the location I want:

```
colors = [:red :blue :green :yellow]

p = [
  plot(col, legend=false, color=colors[idx])
  for (idx, col) in enumerate(eachcol(data))
]

p1 = plot((1:4)', legend=true, framestyle=:none, color=colors)

plot(
  p...,
  p1,
  layout = @layout[
    [
      grid(2, 2)
      p
    ] p1
  ],
  size = (1000, 1000)
)
```

result of `savefig`:
[image]

If I change the layout like the following:

```
layout = @layout[
  p1 [
    grid(2, 2)
    p
  ]
]

# And change the order of the plots
plot(
  p1,
  p...,
  ⋮
)
```

Then I get this:
[image]

Note that I cropped the redundant area of the image above.